# Any way to achieve what 'curl -s -w %{redirect_url} "some_url"' does with 'Invoke-WebRequest'?

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to convert following from bash to PowerShell:

```
url="https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/19/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse"
fetch_url=$( curl -s -w %{redirect_url} "${url}" )
fname=$( curl -OLs -w %{filename_effective} "${fetch_url}" )
```

Executing the above with bash sets `$fetch_url` to `https://github.com/adoptium/temurin19-binaries/releases/download/jdk-19.0.2+7/OpenJDK19U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_19.0.2_7.tar.gz` or, if there is no URL available, to `{"errorMessage":"No releases match the request"}` and the command returns with a return code other than "0".

Executing the next line `$fname` will be `OpenJDK19U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_19.0.2_7.tar.gz`. The file is downloaded to this name, because `curl` was called with `-OLs`. (`-O`: output to name found within url; `-L`: follow redirects; `-s`: silent; `-w %{filename_effective}`: selects the resulting filename to be reported on stdout). `$fname` then holds this filename for later use.

Any idea how to make the same happen with `Invoke-WebRequest`? For the URL given this only returns

```
> Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/19/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse"
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {31, 139, 8, 0…}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "0x8DAFB9194B2EB0B"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: a6f360ad-e01e-004e-7f8b-470ced000000
x-ms-version: …
Headers           : {[Connection, System.String[]], [ETag, System.String[]], [Server, System.String[]], [x-ms-request-id, System.String[]]…}
RawContentLength  : 200079543
RelationLink      : {}
```

There seems to be no way to find out the real download-url and filename as with curl. I've tried with (`$curl` set to `C:\cygwin\bin\curl.exe`):

```
$fetch_url = &$curl -s -w %{redirect_url} "$api_url"
```

Instead of using `Invoke-WebRequest`. But this leads the server asking for authentication -- not what was intended. Any idea how to make one or the other work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that **modern Windows versions now come with `curl.exe`**, so you could simply **translate your Bash script to PowerShell**:

```bash
$url = 'https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/19/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse'
$fetch_url = curl.exe -s -w '%{redirect_url}' $url
$fname= curl.exe -OLs -w '%{filename_effective}' $fetch_url

# === Extra code for diagnostic output and error handling.

# Show the resulting variable values.
[pscustomobject] @{
  URL = $url
  FetchUrl = $fetch_url
  FileName = $fname
} | Format-List

# Throw an error, if the last curl call indicated failure.
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw "curl failed with exit code $LASTEXITCODE." }
```

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, be sure to use `curl.exe`, i.e. include the filename extension, so as to bypass the built-in `curl` *alias* that refers to `Invoke-WebRequest` - this problem has been fixed in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).
- The `%{…}` arguments are enclosed in `'…'`, because `{` and `}` are *metacharacters* in PowerShell (they enclose [script-block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) literals, `{…}`)

---

It *is* possible to **implement your task using [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)**, but it is **more cumbersome**:

- *Windows PowerShell* solution:

```bash
$url = 'https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/19/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse'

# Get the (immediate) redirection URL from the response header's 'Location' field.
# Note the need for -MaximumRedirection 0, to suppress the automatic
# redirection that Invoke-WebRequest performs *by default*.
$fetch_url = (Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0  $url).Headers.Location

# Extract the last component from the redirection URL and use it as the file name.
$fname = Split-Path -Leaf $fetch_url

# Perform the download, silently.
& {
  $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
  Invoke-WebRequest -ErrorAction Stop -OutFile $fname $fetch_url
}
```

- [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) solution (verified in v7.3.2):

  - Unfortunately, the **`Invoke-WebRequest`** call requires extra work, due to **changes in behavior**:

    - A `302` HTTP status code, indicating redirection, is now considered a (statement-terminating) *error* by default, which must be suppressed with `-SkipHttpErrorCheck` in order to get the header data returned.
    - Even with `-SkipHttpErrorCheck`, a non-terminating error is *also* emitted, stating `The maximum redirection count has been exceeded [...]`, which can be silenced with `-ErrorAction Ignore`.
    - Header field values are now `[string[]]` typed. Given that only *one* redirection URL is present, simply accessing element `[0]` is sufficient.
    - [Official list of all changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3#changes-to-web-cmdlets)
  - Therefore, replace the *first* `Invoke-WebRequest` call above with the following:

```bash
$fetch_url = (Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -SkipHttpErrorCheck -ErrorAction Ignore $url).Headers.Location[0]
```

---

**Taking a step back**:

- Targeting the ultimately redirected-to URL returns a **`Content-Disposition` header** that **contains a *suggested download file name***:

  ```bash
  attachment; filename=OpenJDK19U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_19.0.2_7.tar.gz
  ```
- You can let `curl` use this file name by combining the `-O` (`--remote-name` option with `-J` (`--remote-header-name`)

  - Note: The suggested file name *happens to be* the same as the last segment of the (immediate) redirection URL in the case at hand, but there is no guaranteed relationship between the two.
  - The **`curl` `man` page contains a *warning*** regarding `-J`:

> Exercise judicious use of this option, especially on
> Windows. A rogue server could send you the name of a DLL or
> other file that could be loaded automatically by Windows or some
> third party software.

If you want to take advantage of `curl`'s `-J` option, your code can be simplified to:

```bash
# Directly saves to file `OpenJDK19U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_19.0.2_7.tar.gz` 
# and prints its name.
$fname = curl.exe -sLJO -w '%{filename_effective}' $url
```

Note:

- `Invoke-WebRequest` has *no* support for honoring a `Content-Disposition` field.

  - You can extract the file name from it *manually*, in a separate step, as follows:

    ```bash
    (Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Head).Headers['Content-Disposition'] -replace '^.*\bfilename\*?="?([^;"]+)?.*', '$1'
    ```
- In fact, up to at least PowerShell 7.3.2, it doesn't even have support for using the URL's last segment (no equivalent to `curl`'s `-O`): a file name must *explicitly* be passed to the `-OutFile` parameter:

  - However, [GitHub PR #19007](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/19007) will bring such support to a *future* PowerShell version, namely the ability to specify only a *directory* path to `-OutFile`, with the file name being implied by the last segement of the URL, albeit of the *redirected-to* URL (unlike what `curl`'s `-O` does when combined with `-L`)

Comment: WOW - this is beautifully put together, upvote this answer please!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of a hack, curious to see if anyone has a better approach

```
$url = "https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/19/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing -Method HEAD

$null = $response.RawContent -match 'filename=([^\r\n]*)'
$fileName = $matches[1]
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "C:\temp\$fileName"
```

Comment: That is clever, but could be more robust: `(Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Head).Headers['Content-Disposition'] -replace '^.*\bfilename\*?="?([^;"]+)?.*', '$1'`. That is, you can limit the extraction to the `Content-Disposition` header field, and [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) says that the value should be enclosed in `"..."`, though isn't always; there can also be a variant field named `filename*` (sic). It is also worth noting that the OP's own approach uses the _last URL segment_ as the file name, which only _happens to be_ the same